# require(vendor/function.php): Failed to open stream in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed laravel recently via composer but in browser it shows these errors

> Warning:
> require(D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-8.x\vendor\composer/../symfony/deprecation-contracts/function.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-8.x\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
> 69
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> 'D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-8.x\vendor\composer/../symfony/deprecation-contracts/function.php'
> (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-8.x\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
> 69

Answer (score 1):

Do a `php artisan config:clear` to clear all the cached configurations. You might have installed it in a directory that previously had Laravel installed in.